# Spark write inserting certain records twice

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am currently using azure databricks to read from a large file and insert each record into a table.  My code looks like:

```
var readNewFile = spark.emptyDataFrame

readNewFile = spark.read
  .option("header", header)
  .option("multiLine", "true")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv(landingPath)

readNewFile = readNewFile.repartition(50)

var lastDf = readNewFile.withColumn("type_data", lit(type))

  val props = new Properties()

props.put("user", s"${username}")
props.put("password", s"${password}")
  
   lastDf.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append) // <--- Append to the existing table
  .jdbc(s"jdbc:mysql://mydb",databaseSystem+"."+tableName, props)
```

depending on my file size the number of records is always different after about 50k.  If my file size if 50k or less it inserts the exact amount.  If the file gets larger, certain records are inserted multiple times.  I added the repartition code to see if that will work, but it still fails sometimes.  I do not understand repartition enough to know how to fix this issue.  I was told to change the save mode to overwrite, but I feel like there has to be a better way to do this than to overwrite records that have already been inserted.

Comment: Spark may insert same row multiple times if the task is failed and re-run. look in UI for failures

Comment: Or due to speculative execution, which can be turned off.

If the above 2 methods don't fit, you can assign a Primary Key and handle duplicates by writing custom SQL and using: `... ON DUPLICATE KEY <pk>=<pk>`